# How can I auto-fill a paragraph in Eclipse?

Tags: python, eclipse, formatting, word-wrap

I would like to auto-fill a paragraph to 80 characters (or some other fixed width) in Eclipse. Is this possible via a keyboard command like in Emacs? Or is there maybe a plugin (I did not find anything on google)?

Edit: I am not sure if this is relevant, but I need this for docstrings in Python code (using the PyDev plugin).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can wrap the paragraph in Pydev with Ctrl+2+w (see Pydev keybindings at: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_keybindings.html)

Answer (score 2):

Highlight the text, then press Ctrl-Shift-F, or open the context menu and select Source / Format.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work in my case (Python project with PyDev in Eclipse 3.4.2). Maybe it's because of PyDev?

Comment: Could be. I suspect it's context sensitive... I've always used it in Java. I'll keep this answer here, at least for the moment, for the sake of posterity...

Comment: Yes, the answer should stay. At least I now know that this might be due to a shortcoming of PyDev.

Comment: Note that unlike the sophisticated command Emacs provides, this Eclipse command apparently only adds line breaks and never removes them -- it's better than nothing, but it doesn't really save very much work when trying to fix formatting after editing a comment.

Comment: @Porculus: Hmm... it works fine in Java, adding or removing line breaks as required with no problems. What context are you talking about?